# Random reading from file (perl)

Tags: perl

In this section of code I need to read from `file.txt` randomly:

```
...
open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) { 
next unless /\S/;
chomp;
my $response = $ua->get( "http://$_.domain.tld/" );
...
```

How to read lines from `file.txt` randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are accessed sequentially.

What you can do is read the entire file into an array and select a random entry from that.

Comment: More specific: TEXT files are read sequentially.

Comment: So I should have added "on the system level". Different types of files is an abstraction some programming languages offer, and the read(2) syscall (fairly directly available by the perl function sysread) "only" supports reading a number of bytes (but you can of course seek around as much as you want, and nowadays there's also pread(2)) so anything else is basically always achieved by some kind of caching.